# Text in choropleth map Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly, maps

I am trying to add text on each region of this country. this is my code:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="VS 2022 MTD",
                           locations=total_categoria["depto"],
                           featureidkey="properties.name",
                           center={"lat": -33.38160714046037, "lon": -56.5245340},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=5,color_continuous_scale="RdYlGn",
                          )

                           
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="VS 2022 MTD",
                           locations=total_categoria["depto"],
                           featureidkey="properties.name",
                           center={"lat": -33.38160714046037, "lon": -56.5245340},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=5,color_continuous_scale="RdYlGn",
                          )
                           
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

I tried several things, like adding `hover_name=total_categoria["depto"]`  or

```
# Add text annotations
for i, row in total_categoria.iterrows():
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=[row["latitude"]],  # Assuming you have a "latitude" column in your DataFrame
        lon=[row["longitude"]],  # Assuming you have a "longitude" column in your DataFrame
        mode='text',
        text=row["depto"],
        textposition="bottom",
    ))
```

But I am not getting to show the values on each location. Any idea?

[image country without values shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ6eo.png)

Comment: This seems like the same question as the example I recently answered, so please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233077/label-for-geopandas-choropleth/77235025#77235025).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I tried with your posting but is still not showing me the values. I used this:   fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(geojson=geojson,
                            locations=total_categoria["depto"],
                            text=total_categoria["depto"],#["VS 2022 MTD (en %) Total Cat"],
                            textfont=dict(size=8, color='blue'),
                            mode='text')
             )

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)

Comment: The code in the comments looks fine, but I can't even reproduce it without the geojson file and user data, so can I post it?